# Whats the right way to route in magento?

Tags: xml, magento

I'm working with admin routes in magento and I've come across 2 ways of doing them but I'm not sure which is the correct way ?

Router 1 :

```html
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <tradecounter>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Relentless_Tradecounter_Adminhtml</module>
                    <frontName>tradecounter_admin</frontName>
                </args>
            </tradecounter>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

which works and router 2 :

```html
         <adminhtml>
             <args>
                 <modules>
                     <tradecounter before="Mage_Adminhtml">Relentless_Tradecounter_Adminhtml</tradecounter>
                 </modules>
             </args>
         </adminhtml>
```

which doesn't seem to work but I've probably made a mistake in the xml.

Thanks in advance

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no wrong way of doing it.
Both of them work just fine.
But I recommend using the second approach.
The advantages are that your module's admin url will start with `admin` instead of `tradecounter_admin`.
This looks more consistent and in case you have a full page cache system (or Varnish for example) you don't need to set a lot of rules for the pages that should now be caches. Just one simple one. "If it starts with admin then don't cache".

Down side. If you have in 2 modules 2 controllers with the same name you get a conflict.
But this can easily be solved by placing your admin controllers inside a separate folder named the same as the module.

So instead of having `Relentless/Tradecounter/controllers/Adminhtml/PageController.php` you should have `Relentless/Tradecounter/controllers/Adminhtml/Tradecounter/PageController.php`.
Then your admin url looks like this `admin/tradecounter_page/index`.

For more guidelines about writing a module [see this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8345/146)

Answer (score 0):

The Router 1 is the right way .

If it is not working yet then you can check capitalization of every module file and directory and xml file .

you can have a good idea using this tutorial.

http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-started-with-building-admin-module-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

I think the first one will work for you. 
So it should be like this :

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <tradecounter>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Relentless_Tradecounter</module>
                <frontName>tradecounter_admin</frontName>
            </args>
        </tradecounter>
    </routers>
</admin>
```